# Webseal not directing the request to custom login.html file

Tags: webseal

WebSeal server implemented in the EAI setup should intercept an user request and redirect to the URL defined in custom login.html file. My new WebSeal has to be configured on AIX and every piece of configuration has been copied from an existing running WebSeal  configured on Linux. On linux the request is getting directed to login.html and the EAI page corresponding to the URL defined in login html page is getting displayed. However, the behaviour is not the same in AIX and the request is not getting redirected login.html file. Is there anything else I should be checking ?

As per the details mentioned above